# Angular velocity and instantaneous rotation axis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Let's suppose that we have a cylinder of moment of inertia $I$ rolling on the floor without sliding, moving with linear velocity $v$ and rotating around an axis passing through the center of mass with angular velocity $\omega = v / R$. (a composition of translation and rotation)

Now if we consider the motion as a rotation around the instant rotation axis, will the angular velocity with respect to that axis be $\omega$ too or will it be different? Will it be the same if the cylinder were sliding?

Comment: Check your math. It should be $$\omega = \frac{v}{R}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is to compare kinetic energies in the two cases:
\begin{align*}
KE &= \tfrac{1}{2}I_{\text{cm}}\omega^2_{\text{cm}} + \tfrac{1}{2}M(R\omega)^2_{\text{cm}}  \\
KE &=\tfrac{1}{2}I_{\text{inst}}\omega_{\text{inst}}^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} (I_{\text{cm}} + MR^2)\omega^2_{\text{inst}}
\end{align*}
So $\omega_{\text{inst}}=\omega_{\text{cm}}$. The first equation is rotational KE plus translational KE (remember that $\omega = v/R$) for rotation about the center of mass, while the second equation is only rotational energy around the instantaneous axis, where we used the parallel axis theorem.

Note: if the cylinder was sliding then the translational kinetic energy in the first equation will be less than $\tfrac{1}{2}M(R\omega)^2_{\text{cm}} $, so you have to replace the the above system with
\begin{align*}
KE &< \tfrac{1}{2}I_{\text{cm}}\omega^2_{\text{cm}} + \tfrac{1}{2}M(R\omega)^2_{\text{cm}}  \\
KE &=\tfrac{1}{2}I_{\text{inst}}\omega_{\text{inst}}^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} (I_{\text{cm}} + MR^2)\omega^2_{\text{inst}}
\end{align*} 
there for $\omega_{\text{inst}}<\omega_{\text{cm}}$, consistent with intuition.